# How to change the Fedex label type?

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

In our current configuration Magento generates labels to be printed on a laser printer. I am trying to find out how to configure it to generate labels to be printed on the thermal printer provided by fedex.

We are using Magento CE 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's so funny, I had this issue 2 years ago, spent a day on the phone with FedEx and fixed it, then I updated to 1.9 last night and it broke again and I completely forgot how I fixed it so I'm googling around without avail... only to vaguely remember that I might've left a note for myself, and low and behold I had the answer in my Evernote... Leaving it here for anyone else who may be banging their head.

Path: `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php` - Around *Line 1119*

CHANGE:

```
'LabelSpecification' => array(
     'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D',
     'ImageType'       => 'PNG',
     'LabelStockType'  => 'PAPER_8.5X11_TOP_HALF_LABEL’,
```

to

```
'LabelSpecification' => array(
     'LabelFormatType' => 'COMMON2D',
     'ImageType'       => 'PNG',
     'LabelStockType'  => 'PAPER_4X6’,
```

If you change to `ImageType` to `ZPLII` or `EPL2` as suggested by FedEx support, it will work for their end, but the label they send back to you will create an error for the Magento PDF generator. The PDF you download will not open.

Print Labels for FedEx Review
Update Service and Rate files: `app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/wsdl/FedEx`
Open the `ShipService WSDL` and scroll down to the end of the `WSDL`.
Change the value of the attribute `location` in the element `address` from `https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship` to `https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship`